# What is the definition of a “case” in grammar?

Tags: terminology, cases

[Among others, according to Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case)

> "Case" is a linguistics term regarding a manner of categorizing nouns,
> pronouns, adjectives, participles, and numerals according to their
> traditionally corresponding grammatical functions within a given
> phrase, clause, or sentence. In some languages, nouns, pronouns,
> adjectives, determiners, participles, prepositions, numerals, articles
> and their modifiers take different inflected forms, depending on their
> case.

Among others, according to Steven Pinker's [The Sense of Style: The Thinking Person's Guide to Writing in the 21st Century](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=FzRBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA310&dq=linguistics%20nominative%20case&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr1JHA_-HsAhUi5eAKHQBuBuw4FBDoATAEegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The marking of a noun to indicate its grammatical function, including
> nominative case (for subjects), genitive case (for determiners,
> including possessives), and accusative case (for objects and
> everything else).

To my reading, according to Wikipedia definition, the marking of the noun (inflection) is not an inseparable element of the term `case`; but according to the other definition, `case`, in a sense, *is* the “marking of a noun to indicate its grammatical function.” (Even though languages such as English has largely lost its inflected case system.)

Put another way, would the linguistic term `case` exist had there been no such thing as inflection?

---

### ADDENDUM

---

The following quote from the book *Theories of Case* by **Miriam Butt** (suggested by @purlupar) makes me even more confused:

> English does not allow the same freedom in word order as Latin.
> Instead of overt marking on the noun, it makes use of the position of
> of the noun in the sentence in order to indicate the seer vs. the
> thing being seen. (p.4)

Again, to my reading, the quote suggests that `marking` is not supposed to be in the form of overt morphological markers, but using position (or word order) is also a way of `marking.`

Comment: No. Nor would it exist if there had been no such thing as a noun or a grammatical relation.

Comment: "Case" is a tough one, and probably neither Wikipedia nor that dude you cite here would give a satisfying cross-linguistic (meaning not English-centered) explanation. See https://doi.org/10.1017%2Fcbo9781139164696 for a view that's not biased by English but takes into account South-East Asian languages, with are different in this respect.

Comment: WALS [chapters 49](https://wals.info/chapter/49) thru 52 (49 Number of Cases, 50 
Asymmetrical Case-Marking, 51
Position of Case Affixes, 52
Comitatives and Instrumentals) are on various parts of `case` in languages of the world.

Comment: @purlupar From the book you mentioned: **Indeed, a survey of all the phenomena which have been described as “case” leads one to the conclusion that one does not know what case really is.**

Comment: Re: "Indeed, a survey of all the phenomena which have been described as “case” leads one to the conclusion that one does not know what case really is" - no, this is simply not true. While there is a lot of variation in terminology, inventory, and theoretical background, I'd argue almost all linguists would agree on this: cases express grammatical relations of a nominal, e.g. Malchukov, A.  (2017, March 29). Case. Oxford Research Encyclopedia of Linguistics. Retrieved 1 Nov. 2020, from https://oxfordre.com/linguistics/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-247.

Comment: What Pinker says is more of less accurate cross-linguistically  (and his examples are English because the book you mention is about how to write better in English) - and "dude" is not what we usually call Steven Pinker (who turned 66 this year I believe), one of the leading psychologists and psycholinguists, who works at Harvard btw.

Comment: As an example, here are two definitions of *case* I found in the books I just grabbed from my shelf, Dixon 2010/2013: CASE “a system of nominal inflections, marking the syntactic function of a noun phrase in its clause” (p. 333, v.1) or Luraghi and Parodi 2008: CASE “An inflectional category of nouns that helps identify a NP’s grammatical relation and/or semantic role; often also called ‘morphological case’ to distinguish it from abstract Case, a concept used in some formal approaches […] and from deep cases, assumed in Fillmore’s Case Grammar, which correspond to semantic roles” (p. 69)

Comment: @AlexB. What are the names of the books you mentioned?

Comment: Case is easier to understand in languages that decline: Sanskrit, Classical Greek, Latin, German, etc.

Comment: There is really nothing confusing in the quote. Grammatical relations can be expressed differently - btw they are not limited to NPs (like morphological case) - and in a language in which there are cases - grammatical relations of NPs are also expressed via morphological cases.

Comment: I don't think you'd benefit from reading Miriam Butt at this point - she focuses primarily on the differences of case in syntactic theories - which assumes some kind of basic understanding of what case is. I'd say start with Blake, e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B0080430767029648

Comment: Dixon 2010/2013 stands for https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/basic-linguistic-theory-volume-1-9780199571062?cc=us&lang=en& and Luraghi and Parodi 2008 is https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/key-terms-in-syntax-and-syntactic-theory-9780826496553/

Comment: About grammatical relations you should read Payne chapter 8 http://naunicol-e.home.amu.edu.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Payne_Ch_8.pdf (very clear!), **especially page 211** (at the top)

Comment: It's also worth considering them as theoretical primes, as in Relational Grammar or Arc Pair Grammar. Grammatical relations are independent from strictly phrasal phenomena, like parts of speech, and quite variable from language to language -- there are plenty of languages where the concept of "subject" simply does not exist, for instance, or where it introduces unnecessary epicycles if you refer to it.